# Заливка участка g при наведении на SVG

Tags: css, svg

Добрый день. Никак не могу изменить цвет у некоторой `g` в `svg` при наведении.

На странице есть картинка `SVG=logo` c одной из `G=d1`

Вставка:

```
<svg  class="logo" width="74" height="22">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#logo"></use>
</svg>
```

Теперь хотелось бы, чтобы при наведении на `svg` менялась заливка `g`-шечки на другой цвет.

```
.d1 {
fill: #D22856;
}

.d1:hover {
fill: #283645;
}

.logo:hover {
fill: #283645; 
}

.logo:hover g {
fill: #283645; 
}

.logo:hover #d1 {
fill: #283645; 
}
```

Чего только не пробовал - ничего не помогает.
Буду признателен за совет.

Comment: Вы видите тег `g` у вас в `svg`? Я нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример, здесь даже не надо много знать о `svg`։

```html
<svg  class="logo" width="150" height="150">
    <style>
        .circle_g>circle{
            stroke-miterlimit: 5;
            fill:black;
        }
        .circle_g:hover>circle{
            fill: red;
            stroke: red;
        }
    </style>
    <g class="circle_g">
        <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=40 fill=black stroke="black" stroke-width="20"></circle>
    </g>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#logo"></use>
</svg>
```

```css
.circle_g>circle{
    stroke-miterlimit: 5;
    fill:black;
}
.circle_g:hover>circle{
    fill: red;
    stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg  class="logo" width="150" height="150">
    <g class="circle_g">
        <circle cy=100 cx=100 r=40 fill=black stroke="black" stroke-width="20"></circle>
    </g>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#logo"></use>
</svg>
```

`CSS` можете подключить как душа пожелает.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Только мне нужно без style внутри svg.

Comment: @Rotro Посмотрите на обновленный ответ.